# Is there any gem for creating payslip in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem how to create payslip for employees.Is there any gem or api for creating payslip for rails applications.Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can think of a payslip as an 'invoice', its just the reverse direction. So, any of the invoicing gems could be useful

For example, the [payday](https://github.com/commondream/payday) gem or the [Invoicing](https://github.com/gmoeck/invoicing) gem